# How to combine elements of 2 lists in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have following problem:

I have 2 lists:

List a: ['a', 'b', 'c']
List b: ['1', '2', '3']

I want to combine booth, so i got this as a result: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']

How can i get this in ansible?

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ a|zip(b)|map('join')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - a1
  - b2
  - c3
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!